# Como extrair o ícone de um arquivo .exe usando python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, icons

Simplesmente me veio a necessidade de ter um arquivo de imagem .ico extraído de um arquivo .exe e não sei nem como começar. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775690/3846228), você pode utilizar o código abaixo. Eu testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

**Código:**

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\foobar2000\\foobar2000.exe",0)
win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ico_x, ico_x)
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)
hdc.DrawIcon((0,0), large[0])

hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, 'icon.bmp')
```

**Output:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Se quiser entender melhor o funcionamento dele, sugiro que entre na documentação das bibliotecas importadas e veja quais os métodos utilizados:

- `win32api`

  - `.GetSystemMetrics()`
- `win32con`

  - `.SM_CXICON()`
  - `.SM_CYICON()`
- `win32gui`

  - `.ExtractIconEx()`
  - `.DestroyIcon()`
- `win32ui`

  - `.CreateDCFromHandle()`
  - `.CreateBitmap()`
  - `.CreateCompatibleBitmap()`
  - `.CreateCompatibleDC()`
  - `.SelectObject()`
  - `.DrawIcon()`
  - `.SaveBitmapFile()`

---

Para converter a imagem gerada em `.bmp` para `.ico`, você pode utilizar o [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/), como neste exemplo:

**Código:**

```
from PIL import Image

filename = 'icon.bmp'

img = Image.open(filename)

img.save('logo.ico')
```

**Output:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso criou uma imagem em formato bitmap... dá pra usar esse formato como ícone?

Comment: Alterei minha resposta, dê uma olhada.